# How to save fasttext model in vec format?

Tags: python, word-embedding, fasttext

I trained my unsupervised model using `fasttext.train_unsupervised()` function in python. I want to save it as vec file since I will use this file for `pretrainedVectors` parameter in `fasttext.train_supervised()` function. `pretrainedVectors` only accepts vec file but I am having troubles to creating this vec file. Can someone help me?

Ps. I am able to save it in bin format. It would be also helpful if you suggest me a way to convert bin file to vec file.

Answer (score 15):

To obtain VEC file, containing merely all words vectors, I took inspiration from [bin_to_vec official example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/doc/examples/bin_to_vec.py).

```
from fasttext import load_model

# original BIN model loading
f = load_model(YOUR-BIN-MODEL-PATH)
    lines=[]

# get all words from model
words = f.get_words()

with open(YOUR-VEC-FILE-PATH,'w') as file_out:
    
    # the first line must contain number of total words and vector dimension
    file_out.write(str(len(words)) + " " + str(f.get_dimension()) + "\n")

    # line by line, you append vectors to VEC file
    for w in words:
        v = f.get_word_vector(w)
        vstr = ""
        for vi in v:
            vstr += " " + str(vi)
        try:
            file_out.write(w + vstr+'\n')
        except:
            pass
```

The obtained VEC file can be big.
To reduce file size, you can adjust the format of vector components.

If you want to keep only 4 decimal digits, you can replace `vstr += " " + str(vi)` with

 `vstr += " " + "{:.4f}".format(vi)`

Comment: ValueError: Dimension of pretrained vectors (7598805550878845300) does not match dimension (300)! Unfortunately it gives me this error when I try to use the  vec file that I created in that way. It seems it doesn't keep the dimensions of the word vectors that are supposed to be 300.

Comment: I received a similar error: "ValueError: Dimension of pretrained vectors (0) does not match dimension (100)!" I fixed the problem by adding the output of this code: str(len(words)) + " " + str(f.get_dimension()) to the first line of the file, as suggested by @darwin007

Comment: I would use read/write type "a" with extreme caution. In fact, there is no value to use "a" after the last change to the answer. If you run the line of code more than once, you will end up appending the word length, dimensions, and all the words and vectors every time you run that line of code. Using "w" instead of "a" will rewrite the file every time you run the code, which is what you probably want. Full line solution: with open(YOUR-VEC-FILE-PATH,'w') as file_out:

Answer (score 1):

you should add words num and dimension at first line of your vec file, than use -preTrainedVectors para

Answer (score 0):

You can also try generating your fasttext embeddings with the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html) library. The gensim model has a `wv.save_word2vec_format` function that makes generating `.vec` files straightforward.

```
from gensim.models import FastText

sentences = open('data.txt','r').readlines() #data.txt contains a sentence on every line.

#Apply your desired tokenisation method to the sentences
tokenized_sentences = tokenize(sentences)

model = FastText(vector_size=300, window=5, min_count=1, sentences=tokenized_sentences, epochs=10)

#Save vectors to .vec file
model.wv.save_word2vec_format("embeddings.vec")
```