# load custom vectors from fasttext into spacy

Tags: spacy, word-embedding, fasttext

I created my own word vectors with fasttext like so:

```
model = fasttext.train_unsupervised("corp.txt", model = "skipgram") #train model
model.save_model("`my_model.bin`") #save model
```

I would now like to load a spacy model with my vectors. For this, I would have to run the following command to create a spacy model

```
python3 -m spacy init-model de model --vectors-loc some_file.vec
```

and then I should be able to load it like so:

```
nlp = spacy.load('model')
```

My problem is, that I need to feed the vectors and not the model into the command (`some_file.vec`) but I only have a `my_model.bin` file, containing the model.
I know that I can get specific vectors from the model like so

```
print(model["test"])
```

and could loop over all words to get all vectors. But

1. I dont know how the .vec file should look like and
2. I'm sure there has to be a better way to approach this.

ANY help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I just realised, I just had to convert the .bin file into an .vec file. I didn't know that this was easy to do. The code posted  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337469/how-to-save-fasttext-model-in-vec-format) helped me